# Bug resume with Game Libgdx (Pixmap)

Tags: android, libgdx

Before click button "HOME".

[image]

After resume game, scroll error.

[image]

I used to code in show():

```
Pixmap pix = new Pixmap(Gdx.files.internal("data/bgplay_10.png"));
    background_play = new Texture(pix);
    background_play.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat,
            Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat);
    sprite = new Sprite(background_play, 0, 0, 800, 192);
    sprite.setSize(800, 192);
    sprite.setPosition(0, 288);
```

And render():

```
scrollTimer -= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() / 2;
    if (scrollTimer > 1)
        scrollTimer = 0;

    sprite.setU(scrollTimer);
    sprite.setU2(scrollTimer + 1);
```

How to debug or instead ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are responsible for managing textures that are created from Pixmaps. If, instead, you passed that FileHandle into the Texture constructor, LibGDX would manage it automatically. If you want to use the Pixmap, you'll need to reload the image yourself.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I came up with can be found at the following link. It allows you to make the Texture from a pixmap and be managed.

[How to handle resume for libGDX Image with Pixmap texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522946/how-to-handle-resume-for-libgdx-image-with-pixmap-texture/22620025#22620025)